# Dynamically appended text field value not geting printed through id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

it is working for first row and after adding second row it is not running please help me to resolve the issue

i Want to use dynamically added text field value in java script

Form

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <select required id="itemname-1" name="itemname[]" class="form-control" onchange='showUser(this)'>
      <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select Item Code</option>
    </select>;</td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-2" id="quantity-1" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity[]" style='float:left' onchange="getdetails(this);">
    <p id="parameterr-1" style='float:left'></p><input type="hidden" name='parameter[]' id='parameter-1'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-2" id="bp-1" placeholder="Basic Price" name="price[]" onchange="getdetails(this);">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-2" id="gst-1" placeholder="GST" name="gst[]" readonly='readonly'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-2" id="tbp-1" placeholder="Total Basic Price" name="tbp[]" readonly='readonly'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-2" id="tgst-1" placeholder="Total GST" name="tgst[]" readonly='readonly'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" diasabled class="form-control col-xs-2" id="tot-1" placeholder="Total" name="grand[]" readonly='readonly'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addCF">
      <button class="btn-primary btn">Add</button>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Add Button

```
<td>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addCF">
    <button class="btn-primary btn">Add</button>
  </a>
</td>
```

ADD Form Script

```
var i = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addCF").click(function() {

    $("#customFields").append("<tr><td><select required id='itemname-" + i + "' name='itemname[]' class='form-control' onchange='showUser(this);'><option value=''>Select Item Code</option><?php $q='SELECT * FROM items where category="
      Raw Material "';$res=mysqli_query($con,$q);while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {echo " < option value = '". $row['
      itemid ']."' > " .$row['item_code'] ." < /option>" ;}echo "</select > " ;?></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='quantity-" + i + "' placeholder='Quantity' name='quantity[]' value='0' onchange='getdetails(this);'><p id='parameterr-" + i + "' style='float:left'></p><input type='hidden'name='parameter[]' id='parameter-" + i + "'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='bp-" + i + " ' placeholder='Basic Price' value='0' name='price[]' onchange='getdetails(this);'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='gst-" + i + "' placeholder='GST' readonly='readonly' name='gst[]'  onblur='tax()'></td><td><input type='text'  class='form-control col-xs-2' id='tbp-" + i + "' readonly='readonly' placeholder='Total Basic Price' name='tbp[]'></td><td><input type='text'  class='form-control col-xs-2' id='tgst-" + i + "' placeholder='Total GST' name='tgst[]' readonly='readonly'></td><td><input type='text' readonly='readonly' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='tot-" + i + "' placeholder='Total' name='grand[]'></td><td><a href='javascript:void(0);'' id='remCF'><button class='btn-default btn'>Remove</button></a></td></tr>");

    i++;
  });

  $("#customFields").on('click', '#remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

I am facing issue while running this function

```
function getdetails(str) {
  var name = str.id;
  var res = name.split("-");
  var b = res[1];
  var qtyid = "quantity-" + b;
  var priceid = "bp-" + b;
  var tbpid = "tbp-" + b;
  var tgstid = "tgst-" + b;
  var gstid = "gst-" + b;
  var totid = "tot-" + b;
  alert(priceid);
  var qty = document.getElementById(qtyid).value;
  var price = document.getElementById(priceid).value;
  var gst = document.getElementById(gstid).value;
  if (qty == 0) {
    alert("Please Enter Quantity");
  } else if (price == 0) {
    alert("Please Enter Price");
  } else if (price == 0) {
    alert("Please Enter Price");
  } else if (gst == 0) {
    alert("Please Select Item to place purchase Id");
  } else {
    document.getElementById(tbpid).value = qty * price;
    var tbp = document.getElementById(tbpid).value;
    var gst = document.getElementById(gstid).value;
    document.getElementById(tgstid).value = tbp * (gst / 100);
    var tgst = document.getElementById(tgstid).value;
    document.getElementById(totid).value = tgst + tbp;

  }
}
```

it is working for first row and after adding second row it is not running please help me to resolve the issue

i Want to use dynamically added text field value in java script

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the append string again. Easy solution is to replace :
 THIS

```
$("#customFields").append("<tr><td><select required id='itemname-" + i + "' name='itemname[]' class='form-control' onchange='showUser(this);'><option value=''>Select Item Code</option><?php $q='SELECT * FROM items where category="
  Raw Material "';$res=mysqli_query($con,$q);while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {echo " < option value = '". $row['
  itemid ']."' > " .$row['item_code'] ." < /option>" ;}echo "</select > " ;?></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='quantity-" + i + "' placeholder='Quantity' name='quantity[]' value='0' onchange='getdetails(this);'><p id='parameterr-" + i + "' style='float:left'></p><input type='hidden'name='parameter[]' id='parameter-" + i + "'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='bp-" + i + " ' placeholder='Basic Price' value='0' name='price[]' onchange='getdetails(this);'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='gst-" + i + "' placeholder='GST' readonly='readonly' name='gst[]'  onblur='tax()'></td><td><input type='text'  class='form-control col-xs-2' id='tbp-" + i + "' readonly='readonly' placeholder='Total Basic Price' name='tbp[]'></td><td><input type='text'  class='form-control col-xs-2' id='tgst-" + i + "' placeholder='Total GST' name='tgst[]' readonly='readonly'></td><td><input type='text' readonly='readonly' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='tot-" + i + "' placeholder='Total' name='grand[]'></td><td><a href='javascript:void(0);'' id='remCF'><button class='btn-default btn'>Remove</button></a></td></tr>");
```

WITH

```
$("#customFields").append(`<tr><td><select required id='itemname-" + i + "' name='itemname[]' class='form-control' onchange='showUser(this);'><option value=''>Select Item Code</option><?php $q='SELECT * FROM items where category="
  Raw Material "';$res=mysqli_query($con,$q);while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {echo " < option value = '". $row['
  itemid ']."' > " .$row['item_code'] ." < /option>" ;}echo "</select > " ;?></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='quantity-" + i + "' placeholder='Quantity' name='quantity[]' value='0' onchange='getdetails(this);'><p id='parameterr-" + i + "' style='float:left'></p><input type='hidden'name='parameter[]' id='parameter-" + i + "'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='bp-" + i + " ' placeholder='Basic Price' value='0' name='price[]' onchange='getdetails(this);'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='gst-" + i + "' placeholder='GST' readonly='readonly' name='gst[]'  onblur='tax()'></td><td><input type='text'  class='form-control col-xs-2' id='tbp-" + i + "' readonly='readonly' placeholder='Total Basic Price' name='tbp[]'></td><td><input type='text'  class='form-control col-xs-2' id='tgst-" + i + "' placeholder='Total GST' name='tgst[]' readonly='readonly'></td><td><input type='text' readonly='readonly' class='form-control col-xs-2' id='tot-" + i + "' placeholder='Total' name='grand[]'></td><td><a href='javascript:void(0);'' id='remCF'><button class='btn-default btn'>Remove</button></a></td></tr>`);
```